# How can I make the console.log at the bottom wait until its all complete, then show me the answer instead of waiting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

This is the code I have, I know there has been people to explaining the await functions here but I can not seem to understand why mine is not working, inside the function it console.logs the database perfectly, also on the .then section of code, but when it comes to the console.log outside it won't work.

```
function resolveAfter1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var scoresFromDb = db.account.find({}, { username: 1, score: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) 
              reject(err);
          else
              resolve(result);
              // console.log(result);
    });
  });
}

resolveAfter1() // resolve function
    .then((result)=>{console.log(result);})
    .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);})
```

It won't show on the console.log(result) under either.

```
 async function asyncCall() {
      var result = await resolveAfter1();
      return result
      // console.log(result);
    }
```

To display it under this line, what Im I doing wrong?

```
console.log(asyncCall(), ' why is it still pending?');
```

result on the console.log

```
Promise { <pending> } ' why is it still pending?'
```

Comment: await returns a promise, it does not wait for a value to return. You should still call `.then()` or make the call `await` in the console.log function when asking for the value.

Comment: Problem is that Im then wanting to send these values over to the client side of my game, `socket.emit('allScores', asyncCall());`

Comment: @Andrew Well, you can't. An async call always returns a promise, there's no way to trick time. `await` does not cause the function to synchronously return a future value. You have to use `asyncCall().then(e => socket.emit('allScores', e))` or `socket.emit('allScores', await asyncCall())`.

Answer (score 2):

> `asyncCall` is an async function, you have to `await` for it to
>   resolve.

`console.log(await asyncCall())`

Comment: await is not defined, since its outside the function?

Comment: if the `console.log` is outside an async function, you need to use `then`. `asyncCall().then((data) => {console.log(data)})`

Answer (score 2):

because console.log doesnt wait for the async call to finish. It already evaluates what the value of the asyncCall which therefore is a Pending Promise.

If you want to emit something because of the asyncCall then emit the value inside the asyncCall

```
asyncCall.then((res) => socket.emit('topic', res))
```

Comment: asyncCall().then((res) => socket.emit('topic', res))

Comment: TypeError: asyncCall.then is not a function, thats what I'm getting

Comment: `asyncCall` has to be invoked. It should be `asyncCall().then`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was -

```
asyncCall().then((res) => socket.emit('topic', res))
```

Thanks for those who helped!